# Going live - redirect old URLs to new and ensure Google ranks new site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a new wordpress website that I want to put live.  I need to redirect all the old product URLs to the new and the domain name needs to be pointed to a new server.

I just want to ensure I follow all the correct steps in the correct order and ensure Google knows about these changes and ranks the new website.

Is the below correct?

1. follow wordpress instructions on how to replace uRLs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
2. Upload new website to new server.
3. Change nameservers for domain to point to new server.
4. Write htaccess redirects for products and place on OLD server / website
5. Write htaccess redirects for products and place on NEW server / website

Answer (score 0):

Filbert everything looks ok, but you shouldn't need to write a htaccess for the old server/website. There is no requirement for that, as when the nameservers change over it will be using the new htaccess only.

Other than that, for SEO reason, the 301 redirects will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip step 4, no need to add anything to old host since nothing will be pointing there.

You can also look at a plugin for managing the redirects - may be a bit easier to manage with WordPress admin vs a .htaccess file.